# How can I make `adb shell` have the correct terminal size?

Tags: adb

So `adb shell` has an annoying bug where it doesn't realize that your graphical terminal app is larger than 80x24, so when you try to run any kind of full-screen console apps like vi or emacs (or any ncurses app), it does not take up the full screen, only a small portion of it. Is there a way to fix this easily?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29033010/5025060 for an easy to implement alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE (Feb. 2015): By now, you can just use "phablet-shell". No need to fiddle around with self built scripts any more. That said, if you want to, they should still work.

---

What I usually do is to use ssh instead of adb. That one configures the 
terminal properly (besides setting many other things up better than adb does).

Put this into your ~/.bash_aliases (on the host computer, not the device)

```
alias sd='adb shell start ssh; \
    adb forward tcp:2222 tcp:22; \
    ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -R [localhost]:2222; \
    ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
        phablet@localhost -p 2222'
```

and close/reopen the terminal window.

Now you can just do a "sd" (short for ssh device) and you'll be logged in as 
user phablet on the phone, with a properly configured terminal and a properly 
set up user environment.

Comment: Scroll down for an expansion of this approach that offers a couple advantages.

Comment: This idea has been expanded and is now available in Ubuntu (at least in Utopic). Run `apt-get install phablet-tools` and it comes with a tool called `phablet-shell` which enables SSH on the device, copies your ssh key id down to the device, and then connects in with ssh for a nice smooth terminal experience.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a bug in the terminal - the default setup of the shell on android is just not configured to handle changing window sizes.

After you resize the actual terminal window, use the `resize` command - then use your fullscreen program.

Comment: _busybox resize_ on some builds of Android.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of mzanetti's answer above, I've expanded it to have a couple advantages that I'm now using regularly:

```
function adbshell {
    adb shell start ssh
    adb forward tcp:2222 tcp:22
    ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -R [localhost]:2222
    ssh-copy-id -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
        phablet@localhost -p 2222 2>/dev/null
    scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
        -q -P 2222 -r ~/.bash* ~/.profile* phablet@localhost:/home/phablet
    ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
        phablet@localhost -p 2222
}
```

- It remembers your credentials so you don't have to type your password every time
- It copies your bash config from the host to the device so you can use all your favorite aliases (and custom prompt config!)

Answer (score 0):

When I plan to be in {adb shell} for any length of time, I usually start off with

```
stty columns 132
```

I use it regularly on both rooted and un-rooted devices.

Acknowledging that it's a manual command everytime you start a shell (and not automatic like the mzanetti/robru solution) it's simple and doesn't require a change to using SSH.