# Ringtones in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a Nexus 4 which is currently running the most up to date Ubuntu Touch build. As much as I enjoy the default ringtones and notification sounds included with the OS, I was wondering where the directory which holds said sounds is and how to access it on my PC. I figure if the notification sounds are in .ogg format I should be able to add Android notification sounds and ringtones. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a bug on Lauchpad for this issue. If you mark it as affecting you too, it will increase the bug head and hopefully contribute to getting this fixed soon: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1268097

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the current settings UI just lists the ringtones found in `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones`, which is read only (provided you haven't switched it to writable image mode).

The choice of ringtone is controlled through GSettings, so you could change the ringtone to a file in a different directory using the `gsettings` tool from the command line.  As the `phablet` user, run a command like the following:

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.touch.sound incoming-call-sound /path/to/ringtone.ogg
```

Presumably a way to set custom ringtones will be added to the UI at some point in the future though.

Answer (score 3):

Connect your phone to ubuntu computer.
Copy your music/sound to Music folder.
Open:

```
phablet-shell
```

Inside shell:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
sudo cp /home/phablet/Music/Your\ Ringtone.ogg /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/
```

Also, if you'd like to change the notification or alarm sounds

```
sudo cp /home/phablet/Music/Your\ Notification.ogg /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/notifications/
```

Note 1: You need developer mode on, password set and have the phone unlocked to be able to connect to it and than to use the sudo command on it.

Note 2: OTA updates are likely to revoke your changes.

Answer (score 2):

The gsettings command no longer seems to work.

The good news is that you just need to copy your custom SMS notification tone into `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/notifications/` and copy your custom ringtone into `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/`

Answer (score 2):

First run this command if you are in read only mode.

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Save your own ringtones and notifications using following commands: (Preferred format is `*.ogg`)

```
sudo cp /path/to/your/ringtone/ringtone.ogg /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/
sudo cp /path/to/your/ringtone/ringtone.ogg /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/notifications/
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps to alias your SSH for a resizeable terminal before using gsettings command otherwise you get these annoying line-wraps on the same line:
[How can I make `adb shell` have the correct terminal size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372649/while-testing-ubuntu-touch-how-can-i-make-adb-shell-have-the-correct-terminal)

Having done the above then you can do:

```sh
sd
touch /userdata/.writable_image
reboot

sd
su - phablet

cd /home/phablet/Downloads/
wget http://adequatech.ca/stephenchowsinging.ogg
wget http://adequatech.ca/trekBeepClick.ogg
wget http://adequatech.ca/trekIntercomWhistle.ogg

gsettings set com.ubuntu.touch.sound incoming-call-sound /home/phablet/Downloads/stephenchowsinging.ogg
gsettings set com.ubuntu.touch.sound incoming-message-sound /home/phablet/Downloads/trekBeepClick.ogg
```

For SMS notification sound, try this one:

```sh
gsettings set com.ubuntu.touch.sound incoming-message-sound /home/phablet/Downloads/trekIntercomWhistle.ogg
```