# New ringtones for Ubuntu Phone

Tags: phone

I would like to copy a new ringtone to my BQ Aquarius Ubuntu Edition.
How can I copy ringtones from /home/phablet/Downloads to usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/

Answer (score 2):

Custom ringtones [will arrive with OTA-9](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1268097/comments/39) (Jan 27 2016).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Terminal](https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.terminal) or [File Manager](https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.filemanager) to copy your files. Both can be found on "Ubuntu Store".

There is currently no UI to add new ringtones, and the preinstalled ones are stored in a read-only location. Once you are aware of the implications, [you can try to set your phone in read-write mode](https://askubuntu.com/q/380258/9781)

Further information can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372759/ringtones-in-ubuntu-touch).